# EF Adding additional FK Field with underscore

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have the following EF 6.1.3 code first POCO class:

```
[Table("Users", Schema = "CRM")]
public class User : SqlBaseModel
{

}
```

which generates the following table in SQL Server:

[image: SQL Server User table]

When I add a foreign key property to the model like so:

```
[Table("Users", Schema = "CRM")]
public class User : SqlBaseModel
{
    public Guid? ContactId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

and the corresponding navigation property in Contacts:

```
[Table("Contacts", Schema = "CRM")]
public class Contact : SqlBaseModel
{
    public Guid? AccountId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentContactId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentContactId")]
    public virtual Contact ParentContact { get; set; }

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

it generates the following table in SQL Server:

[image: user table with foreign key]

As you can see, EF generates 2 fields: ContactId and Contact_Id.

Could anyone please advice me as to what is necesary to remove the Contact_Id (with underscore) field? What am I doing wrong that EF generates 2 FK fields?
Thanks

Comment: you are using Users in contact class, it would be better to use fluent configuration api than the attributes

Comment: Thx, will give fluent api a try